# Why is my Xbox 360 not connecting to controller and showing up on my TV?

Tags: technical-issues, xbox-360, controllers

I turned on my Xbox 360 after 6 months and connected it to the TV, but it was not showing up on either HDMI 1 or HDMI 2. The (wireless) controller is also not connecting, which shows on Xbox but rather it keeps flashing. I have also tried changing the HDMI cables.

Answer (score 0):

A bit confused on exactly what the problem is. However what i could get was that the controller has its LED just flashing and not connecting right? Most often it's because the batteries are low and need either new ones or fully charged ones. If that doesn't work, then there's a problem with either the connection sender or the battery case. To that extent i would recommend getting a new controller.

If no controllers can connect to the console at all, I can only imagine that would be because the console's receiver isn't functioning properly or damaged.

I hope for the best, since this is all I know.